# cx_Freeze Attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, cmd, exe, cx-freeze, attributeerror

I am trying to convert a python file into an executable but when i run

```
python setup.py build
```

in my command line, i get error saying

```
Attribute Error:  'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is the issue in my setup file or my main file of my code?

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['Arcade Funk.mp3', 'game over.wav', 'FrogTown.wav','pixel ufo.png','introBackground.png','pixel playButton.png','pixel instructionButton.png','pixel playButtonHighlighted.png','pixel instructionButtonHighlighted.png','instructionPage.png','crashBackground.png','space background long.png','pixel earth.png','pixel asteroid.png', 'pixel icon.png','Montserrat-ExtraBold.otf','Montserrat-Bold.otf','arial.ttf']
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ['pygame']
build_exe_options = {'includes':[includes],'packages':[packages], 'excludes':[excludes], 'include_files':[includefiles]}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = 'Win64GUI'
elif sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(  name = 'Earth Invaders',
        version = '0.1',
        description = 'Slider Game: Space',
        options = {'build_exe': [build_exe_options]},
        executables = [Executable('EarthInvaders.py', base=base)]
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'item' Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087979/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-item-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra brackets in your code, resulting in the unnecessary declaration of additional lists.

Your `build_exe_options` declaration should read:

```py
build_exe_options = {'includes':includes, 'packages':packages, 'excludes':excludes, 'include_files':includefiles}
```

And your options argument should be:

```py
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
```